# Prove or find a counterexample: if $A \subseteq B, B \subseteq C, C \subseteq A$, then $A = B = C$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

Proof or find a counterexample:For all sets A;B;C if $A \subseteq B$, $B\subseteq C$, and $C\subseteq A$, then $A = B = C$.

I tried doing this but not sure whether going in the right way

Let $x\in A\subseteq B$,
 this means if $x\in A$
  then $x\in B$

$x\in B\subseteq C$
 , this means if $x\in B$
  then $x\in C$

$x\in C\subseteq A$
 , this means if $x\in C$
  then $x\in A$

THUS, $x\in
 B\Rightarrow x\in
 C\Rightarrow x\in
 A$ therefore $A=B=C$

can i be provided feedbacks on actually how to do this question

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! I edited your question to format the mathematical symbols. Can you check the new formatting corresponds to what you meant?

Comment: Hint: $A = B \iff (A \subseteq B \wedge B \subseteq A)$.

Comment: can not understand what is the hint trying to say?

Comment: On the hint: To show e.g. that $A = B$ you have to show two things: that $A \subseteq B$ and that $B \subseteq A$. That $A \subseteq B$ is given; how do you show that $B \subseteq A$?

Comment: The answer is in the antisymmetry and transitivity of $⊆$.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/808283/for-all-sets-a-b-c-if-a-subseteq-b-b-subseteq-c-and-c-subseteq-a-the and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/795739/prove-or-find-a-counterexample-if-a-subseteq-b-b-subseteq-c-c-subseteq-a

Answer (score 4):

Start by showing that $A=B$. To do that you need to show that any element $x\in A$ is also in $B$, and that any element $y\in B$ is also in $A$. Start your proof with: let $x\in A$.

Now, you are given that $A\subseteq B$, which thus implies that $x\in B$. So, you have half of what you need.

Now you need to show that anything in $B$ is also in $A$. So, start that part of the proof with: Let $y\in B$.

Now, you are also given that $B\subseteq C$, so that now you can conclude that $y\in C$.

What else are you given? can you use it now to conclude that $y\in A$? If so, then you may conclude that $A=B$. Then you can proceed to show that $B=C$ (in a similar fashion) and finish your exercise.