# If $A\subseteq B$, $B\subseteq C$, and $C\subseteq A$, then $A=B=C$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to determine if the following is true, and if so prove it.

> For all sets $A,B,C$, if $A\subseteq B$
>    , $B\subseteq C$
>     and $C\subseteq A$
>    , then $A=B=C$

Solution:

True

Assume $x\in A$. Since $A\subseteq B$, then $x\in B$.

Assume $y \in B$. Since $B\subseteq C$, then $y\in C$. Since $C\subseteq A$, then $y\in A$.

Therefore $A=B=C$

---

I tried doing this problem again. Can I be assisted with feedback and whether the solution is correct or not.

Comment: I *know* this is a duplicate of a previous question (because I remember writing a comment on it, but I can't find it), but it's impossible to find it by searching. Things like "A ⊆ B ⊆ C ⊆ A ⟹ A = B = C" are basically undiscoverable using the search function.

Comment: @kahen this is the one you are looking for 

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/807331/proof-or-find-a-counterexamplefor-all-sets-abc-if-a-subseteq-b-b-subsete?rq=1

Comment: Also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/795739/prove-or-find-a-counterexample-if-a-subseteq-b-b-subseteq-c-c-subseteq-a

Answer (score 0):

You correctly showed that $A=B$, but it would probably be best to also show that $B=C$.

Comment: Or equivalently that $A = C$ (which is immediate from the inclusions given in the problem since OP proved $A=B$)

Answer (score 0):

The inclusions tell us that $A \subseteq B \subseteq C \subseteq A$.

Now the only subset of $A$ that can contain $A$ is $A$.

Thus $B=A$ and $C=A$.